# how to select from query result in Firebird 1.5

Tags: sql, select, firebird

i got this query for Firebird 1.5 :

```
select * from (
select
ddddd.name,
gggg.land,
dd.maskenkey,
ddd.name,
Sum(b.epreis*a.menge),  
Sum((kx.epreis / lx.kurs) * a.menge),
sum(case when b.bverpa_id='1' then (a.menge*e.p_volume)/e.pcs_box else a.menge*e.P_PCS_20ST end) as jumlah 
from brrcp a  
left outer join baufpo b on a.baufpo_id_aufnrpos = b.id 
left outer join brrc c on a.brrc_id_rgnr = c.id  
left outer join bauf d on b.bauf_id_linkkey = d.id 
left outer join bkunde dd on d.bkunde_id_kunr = dd.id  
left outer join badr ddd on dd.badr_id_adrnr = ddd.id 
left outer join bvert dddd on d.bvert_id = dddd.id  
left outer join badr ddddd on dddd.badr_id = ddddd.id 
left outer join bbesp kx on b.id = kx.baufpo_id_aufpos  
left outer join bbes aa on kx.bbes_id_linkkey = aa.id 
left outer join bsal yy on kx.bsal_id = yy.id  
left outer join bwaer lx on kx.bwaer_id_waehrungk = lx.id  
left outer join bplz zz on ddd.bplz_id_landplz = zz.id 
left outer join bland gggg on zz.bland_id_landkennz = gggg.id 
left outer join bsa e on a.bsa_id_artnr = e.id  
where c.eta_shipment between '01/01/2015' and '6/30/2015'
and dd.maskenkey starting 'AS-' and d.cancel = 'N' and d.confirm = 'N' and aa.status_po <> 'C'  
and d.auftrag = 'J' and a.rg_buchungsart Is Null
group by ddddd.name,gggg.land,dd.maskenkey,ddd.name) abc
```

How to fix its structure because when I want to execute this query, i will get error? Thank you !!

```
**Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 2, char 1.
select.**
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest using more meaningful aliases

Comment: i continued my friend's work. not my own

Comment: Why are you even using `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... )` in this case it is an unnecessary level of indirection.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a select in the `FROM` clause, this is called a [derived table](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes207.html#dml-dsql-derived-tables), and you can't use derived tables in Firebird 1.5 or earlier.

This feature [was introduced 9 years ago in Firebird 2.0](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes207.html#new-derived-tables). So if you want to use this in your queries, you should upgrade (and if you do, upgrade to Firebird 2.5.5). Before you upgrade, please make sure to read through the Firebird 2.0, 2.1 and 2.5 [release notes](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/release-notes/) and the [Firebird 2 Migration & installation Notes](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/install210.html) for any compatibility changes that you need to take into account.

The query in your question itself doesn't need derived tables at all, just remove the outer `SELECT * FROM (....) abc` from your query, it has - as it is posted - no added value.